# Api chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired. Окно в браузере при авторизации прокси на некоторых веб-страницах через api chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, авторизация, chrome-extension, прокси

Возникает алёрт в браузере при авторизации прокси на некоторых веб-страницах через api chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.

Я разработал расширение для chromium и, которое подключается к proxy через api chrome.proxy.settings и авторизую сервер с помощью chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired. Использую Манифест 3 версии.

СУТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ ТАКОГО:
После коннекта к определенному серверу, при перезагрузки страницы в браузере, сервер авторизуется, но на некоторых страницах, особенно сервисах google (например https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions), сервер не авторизуется. Выражается это в появлении системного окна авторизации хрома, с полями для ввода USERNAME PASSWORD c кнопками отмены и подтверждения. Для решения проблемы необходимо перейти на другую вкладку, на ней перезагрузить страницу и вернуться обратно, тогда на странице, где появлялось окно авторизации хрома,оно исчезнет и сервер будет авторизован.

В разных браузерах на chromium разное поведение, но конкретно в chrome такое поведение. Так же, если я закрою браузер и затем снова его открою, но не отключу свое расширение, то снова может появиться окно авторизации, но оно уже исчезнет по нажатию кнопки "Отмена".

Так же, бывает иногда что окно авторизации появляется на любой случайной странице, но достаточно так же нажать "Отмена" и сервер авторизуется.

```
  function authRequired() {
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
      async function (details, callback) {
        const credentials = await new Promise(resolve => {
          chrome.storage.local.get(['selectedIPAddress'], function (result) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(result.selectedIPAddress));
          });
        });
        callback({
          authCredentials: {
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password
          }
        });
      },
      { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
      ['asyncBlocking']
    )
}
authRequired()
```